# how to downgrade spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project build on `2.1.0.RELEASE`.
I want to run this project on *Weblogic* server which is running on a `java1.7` version.
I tried to change the java version in my `pom.xml` to
`<java.version>1.7</java.version>`
but it didn't work.

when I create an executable jar from my project it still showing build_jdk as 1.8 so I decided to switch to *springboot's* older version 1.4.0 expecting it to run on Java 7. However, when I build my project again I don't see any change in the manifest file of the generated jar. It is still showing *springboot* version as `2.1.0.RELEASE`.

can anyone suggest regarding one of the 2 things?

1. Build project with *springboot* 2.1.0 and Java version 7
2. Downgrade *springboot* to 1.4.0 and build with Java 7

here is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" 
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
          <parent>
            <groupId>parent-XYZ-package</groupId>
            <artifactId>parent-XYZ-project</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          </parent>
          
      <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
     
      <name>myProject</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>
      
      <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>exec</classifier>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>            
                <configuration> 
                  <archive> 
                    <mainClass>MyMainClass</mainClass>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        **<dependency>
            <groupId>DependentUserProjec</groupId>
            <artifactId>DependentUserProject</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>**
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>wlfullclient</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
          </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    
    
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
           </dependency>
    
      </dependencies>
      
      
      <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    </project>
```

one more thing to note that I already have a parent pom in my `pom.xml`
Hence I am specifying my *springboot* parent dependency through `<DependencyManagement>` tag.

**Update**

Which ever *springboot* version I specify in pom.xml its always building my project with `Springboot 2.1.1.RELEASE`

Below is the snapshot from my manifest file generated

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: SID    
Start-Class: myMainClass  **This line is I have edited just to post on this site**
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.1.1.RELEASE
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_181
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Comment: First things first, Spring Boot 2 supports a minimum of Java 8; Java 7 is **not supported**.

Comment: Could you please add your code? because you do reference to version 2.1.0 is still being displayed.

Comment: How does parent-XYZ-project pom.xml look like?

Comment: It has 3 modules to build including my Spring boot module I am facing issue with and location of Nexus repositories where we have some other jars. But no reference to spring boot.

Answer (score 1):

**step 1**: change the java version in `pom file`.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

**step 2**: Go to maven and update the project.

[Go to maven and update the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETXoi.png)

More Details on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88-x-XfolC8)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29952800)